# Проблема путей в подключаемом css во vue

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack

После импорта css `import './assets/styles/common.css'` появилась ошибка подключения шрифтов, как это решить?

```
./src/assets/styles/common.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-3-2!./src/assets/styles/common.css)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/PlayfairDisplay/PlayfairDisplay-Black.eot' in 'H:\frontend\WM\WW-vue\src\assets\styles'
```